# How to change properties of a button in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am starting to work on my project and I've decided to use Visual Basic. I've used it in the past but I am quite new with Windows Forms. I want my code to change the background image of the button once I press the said button. However, pressing the button does nothing. Where have I gone wrong?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TitleScreen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TitleScreen.Click
        BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Player1CharacterInformationScreen
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to use `ButtonName.BackgroundImage`. Using `BackgroundImage` alone is equivalent to `Me.BackgroundImage`, where [`Me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass) is the current instance of the class (`Form1`).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! You have, you have resolved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TitleScreen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TitleScreen.Click
        TitleScreen.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Player1CharacterInformationScreen
    End Sub
End Class
```